# Differences between GML and GMLJP2

Tags: image, standards, ontology, jpeg2000, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I'm wondering which are the differences between GML and GMLJP2. I know GMLJP2 is for JPEG2000, however I want to know if anything changes from one GML to the other. I found an ontology of GML and I want to know if it works for JPEG2000. I would appreciate any information/tutorial for understanding this standard better.
Thanks.

Comment: I think `GML` in your question refers to `Geography Markup Language`. The tag `gml` that you added refers to `Game Maker Language`.

Comment: Read the Open Geospatial Consortium docs on this.